# Ajax with jquery mysterious failure

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Hi I am using jquery for ajax .. I followed manuals and examples on net but I cannot see what I am doing wrong. Here is my code :

```
    function ShowSearchResults(search_value){
           var ajShowSearchResults = $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
            url: '../ajquery.php',
            data: {opt : 'srch', val: search_value},
            dataType: "html"
        });

        ajShowSearchResults.done(function(data){
            alert(data);
        });

        ajShowSearchResults.fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus) {
            alert( "Request failed: " + textStatus);
        });
```

Comment: what do you expect it to do and what's going wrong?

Comment: Getting any console messages?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just tested your script on my localhost. I placed **ajquery.php** in the **www** directory and placed **index.html** which contains your script in the directory **www/test** because according to the ajax parameters you have specified **ajquery.php** must be one level up in the directory heirarchy.

The code in **www/ajquery.php:**

```
<?php print_r($_POST); ?>
```

The code in **www/test/index.html:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function ShowSearchResults(search_value){
           var ajShowSearchResults = $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
            url: '../ajquery.php',
            data: {opt : 'srch', val: search_value},
            dataType: "html"
        });

        ajShowSearchResults.done(function(data){
            alert(data);
        });

        ajShowSearchResults.fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus) {
            alert( "Request failed: " + textStatus);
        });
        return false; // My addition
    } // This Bracket You missed in the question

</script>
<form onsubmit='return ShowSearchResults($("#y").val())'>
<input type="text" name="y" id="y"/>
<input type="submit"/>
</form>
```

This is the output.
[image: Output]

Now, You can see that all the `POST` data you sent is available at **ajquery.php**. That proves that there is no problem with your script except the last bracket which, I assume, you left out by mistake. But still, I can smell that there might be a problem in the following line on your side.

```
            url: '../ajquery.php',
```

**ajquery.php** might not be residing in the parent directory. If **ajquery.php** is in the same directory, you can replace `../ajquery.php` with `ajquery.php` or best of all, with the absolute url to **ajquery.php** like `http://yourdomain.com/ajquery.php`.

Hope that solves your question.

Peace...

Comment: Thank you very much !! the problem was with directory of ajquery.php. 
Thank you for your time..

Answer (score 0):

You can put the success and error functions in the ajax call like so:

```
$.ajax(
{
    type:       'POST',
    url:        '../ajquery.php',
    data:       {opt : 'srch', val: search_value},
    dataType:   "html",
    success:    function(data) 
    {
        alert(data);
    },
    error:      function(jqXHR, textStatus)
    {
        alert( "Request failed: " + textStatus);
    }
});
```

I hope this works, because I didn't test it ;)

Answer (score 0):

Wild guess:

```
    var ajShowSearchResults = $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '../ajquery.php',
        data: {opt : 'srch', val: search_value},
        dataType: "html",
        success: searchSuccess,
        failure: searchFailure,
    });

    searchSuccess = function(data) {
        alert(data);
    };

    searchFailure = function(data) {
        alert( "Request failed: " + data);
    };
```